# Paper published at „bad“ conference, share with potential supervisors?

Tags: publications, phd, conference

I’m currently in the process of contacting potential PhD supervisors. I’ve also just published my first paper which was submitted to a conference my work place commonly submits papers to. It’s a WiP paper and mainly conceptual. I have no clue if this paper is actually good, since the conference doesn’t seem to be that reputable (B4 on conference rank). Additionally I pretty much wrote the whole thing without any supervision or feedback.

So now I’m debating whether it could be harmful to share this paper with potential supervisors.

Comment: Whatever the conference, you should have *some* "clue if this paper is actually good". Have you read other papers related to your work, are your results interesting related to the prior work, and are your results backed up by solid evidence? I am sure you have asked yourself those questions at some point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this conference peer reviewed? This would be typical in e.g. computer science, but not as much in many other areas of research.

If this is a peer reviewed, somewhat-reputable conference and not predatory, or "fake" conference (what I mean by that is: I have seen conferences take on similar names to highly prestigious ones, which then make the same acronym, to try and look like a reputable conference which they are not); e.g. if it is a student track of a local conference, I would definitely encourage you to include this published paper in your CV when you apply for any PhD positions.

Many students applying for a PhD won't have any publications to their name at that point; and if they do, it is expected that these would likely be student tracks or smaller local conferences. And, as communicating your work in writing is a major part of a PhD, mentioning this publication gives any potential advisors a way to check out your current writing skills, which is a great skill to be able to demonstrate to potential advisors.

Comment: Yes it’s a peer reviewed international conference definitely not a “fake” conference. It’s more applied so not really technical at all but I hope to do a math heavy and technical CS PhD, because I want to learn more here. I guess this will suffice though for my writing skills, I’m worried that a supervisor would think “well this doesn’t make sense and the idea is stupid” I guess that’s my fear speaking though.

Comment: @amsulic No-one is going to judge you by the same standards that are applied to mature researchers. It may be that for a mature researcher in your field, publishing exclusively at "B4-ranked conferences" (whatever that means) would not be a good sign. That doesn't mean that it's a bad sign for you as someone who has not even started their Ph.D. If Ph.D. applicants were already expected to produce the same quality of work that mature researchers do, then what would even be the point of Ph.D. studies?